# Airdrop w/o cellular and internet

Tags: airdrop

I read that Airdrop will work without internet access. Will Airdrop work without access to a cellular network? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Yes, since AirDrop is also available on the iPod touch and on the Mac which doesn't even have cellular options.

AirDrop is using an Ad-Hoc service for its communication.

[This](https://www.lifewire.com/what-is-airdrop-and-what-types-of-files-can-be-shared-2438226) is a nice article on how AirDrop works.

Comment: That article is, at the very least, out of date (despite it saying it was updated in October 2016) as it states you cannot AirDrop between iOS and macOS, which hasn't been true for at least two years. See https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT203106.

Comment: You're right @tubedogg but what I like about that document is that it gives the user an explanation on how its communication is working

Comment: Right, though to be clear, the version of AirDrop that existed in macOS from Lion until Mavericks was different than the version of AirDrop introduced in iOS 7. See [this](http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/153189/54484) for a succinct explanation.